# Saving config of ‘modules/addons’ to the database

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

I am creating a multi-tenant web app.

Part of this is have some modules / ‘addons’ which I can turn on and off for each user (known as site). For example I might have two modules. Mailchip newsletter form and social media share buttons.

I was thinking of having a table in the db like

```
id | name                       | handler_class
1  | MailChip                   | MailChimpModule
2  | Social Media Share Buttons | SocialMediaShares
```

then, if I want a site to use/have enabled a module, I add a record to a join/pivot table.

```
id | site_id | module_id | config
1  | 1       | 2         | []
```

so here, site_id 1 will have the second module available.

Now the interesting part comes to the config. I was thinking of storing the config for each module as a json array on the pivot table. This way, each of the handler class’s can specify an array of config fields they need.

eg in the SocialMediaShares.php file it might have

```
protected $settings = [‘FacebookPage’ => ‘’, ‘TwitterPage’ => ‘’];
```

then, there are on write/on load events to handle saving or loading this information.

But… I am not sure.

Should I have config as json, or is it better to create separate tables for each of the modules… and is that going to make it confusing.

Would love some input on this from anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I was creating something similar that needed config options to be stored in the DB and I used JSON. I did not have any problems with that approach - JSON is easy to encode/decode + if you think of implementing some AJAX manipulation, JSON is *very friendly with JS* and you can send it directly with a response without querying/modifying/encoding a config data from additional tables. In short I think that separate tables for configuration options it's too big of an overhead, because you may need many of them when having different configuration types for each module.